# Android gradle androidTestApi & testApi configuration obsoleted

Tags: android, testing, android-gradle-plugin

I got 2 modules, module A and module B. Module B depends on module A, module A shares dependency libraries to module B by using `api` configuration.

When setting up test environment, inside module A, I also use `testApi` & `androidTestApi` to make module B using shared test libraries. However, after running gradle sync, I got warning message: `WARNING: Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'`.

Read the provided [link](http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html) and it said that `other modules can't depend on androidTest, you get the following warning if you use the androidTestApi configuration`. Therefore, I must define test libraries in module B in my example for skipping this warning.

I have some questions on this situation:

1. Why one module should not depends on testing dependencies of other module, although it can depend on normal dependencies defined as `api`?
2. Do we have anyway to force module B depends on test libraries of module A without defined these libraries again in module B?

Many thanks

Comment: Hey! Did you find any solution to the following issue? I understand that certain modules can't depend on androidTestApi and that's fine. However I can't find a good reason for testApi being obsolete as well.

Comment: I still don't find any solution until now, too :(

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The way I did this was by creating a custom configuration. In your case inside the `build.gradle` file module A add:

```
configurations {
    yourTestDependencies.extendsFrom testImplementation
}

dependencies {
    // example test dependency
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
    // .. other testImplementation dependencies here
}
```

And in the `build.gradle` of module B add:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation project(path: ':moduleA', configuration: 'yourTestDependencies')
}
```

The above will include all `testImplementation` dependencies declared in module A to module B.

Comment: suppose I have remote library instead of module A, how can i use custom configuration declared in remote library?

Comment: For remote library, I thought using testApi, androidTestApi is correct. But it doesn't work.

Comment: This is for dependencies. What about accessing a class/method of Module A(domain), from Module B(presentation)?

Answer (score 5):

This is [Chris Margonis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1972883/chris-margonis) (Kudos!) answer in Kotlin-DSL:

```kotlin
// "base" module/project
configurations {
    create("testDependencies"){
        extendsFrom(configurations.testImplementation.get())
    }
}

dependencies {
    // example test dependency
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
    // .. other testImplementation dependencies here
}

//another module
dependencies {
    testImplementation(project(path = ":base", configuration = "testDependencies"))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement the accepted answer, in your base module `:core` add a configuration closure:

```
    // build.gradle (core module)
    configurations {  
        testDependencies.extendsFrom testImplementation  
        testRuntimeOnlyDependencies.extendsFrom testRuntimeOnly  
    }
    
    dependencies {
        def junit5_version = "5.6.0"

        // dependencies
        testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junit5_version"  
        testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junit5_version"  
        testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:$junit5_version" 
        testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:$junit5_version"
    }
```

Then in your `feature` module add:

```
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':core') {  
            testImplementation configurations.getByName('testDependencies').allDependencies  
            testRuntimeOnly configurations.getByName('testRuntimeOnlyDependencies').allDependencies  
        }
    }
```

Now your testing dependencies are shared across modules.

**Note**: Modules `core` and `feature` are fictitious, please substitute accordingly.

Comment: Nice solution! but it doesn't work application module in android. do you know a way around this?

Comment: @AouledIssa The solution is not meant to be used with the `app` module because the app module is not a shared module, so your only option is to create a re-usable module for such use-cases.