# Gradle Multi Module Dependency - usage of api and testImplementation together

Tags: android, gradle

I have a module that contains only test dependencies, and I expose those dependencies as `api`

```
// testshared/build.gradle

api libraries.lib1
api libraries.lib2
```

and I use it in `moduleA` with `testImplementation project(':testshared')`

Is this equivalent of creating a custom configuration that extends from testImplementation and use it like this:

```
// testshared/build.gradle

configurations {
    myTestDependencies.extendsFrom testImplementation
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation libraries.lib1
    testImplementation libraries.lib2

    // .. other testImplementation dependencies here
}
```

```
// moduleA/build.gradle

testImplementation project(path: ':testshared', configuration: 'myTestDependencies')
```

as seen as here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53649718/8681368 ?

Answer (score 0):

In case of `testImplementation`, it suffices as dependencies of the application module. Else `api` should only be used (or even must be used), when referencing identical dependencies in multiple modules. `testImplementation` behaves different than regular module dependencies, because they're for a whole other (test) application. Without an application module, integration testing is not possible, because it requires 2 applications. Libraries by themselves can only be unit-tested.

If you want to have an extra file, just `apply from: "testshared/build.gradle"`.

`debugImplementation` also sometimes is required, but `testApi` will only cause:

```
Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
```

It always was a useless configuration, because there only is 1 test application per application module. Using `testImplementation` together with `api` can only be done in the application module.

Comment: Yea actually my app module is moduleA in this case,

Comment: But my other modules' test suites work fine as well with the first setup in my question, not sure what you meant by
 > Using testImplementation together with api can only be done in the application module